# Is the undecidable function $UC$ well-defined for proving the undecidability of Halting Problem?

Tags: computability, proof-techniques, undecidability, halting-problem

I am new to Computability Theory and find it is both amazing and confusing. Specifically, it is difficult for me to get through the undecidability of the well-known Halting Problem.

> **Halting function:** The Halt function takes an input a pair $<\alpha, x>$ and outputs 1 if and only if the TM $M_{\alpha}$ represented by $\alpha$ halts on input $x$ within a finite number of steps.

The undecidability of Halting function is proved by reduction from another undecidable function $UC$, which is defined as follows [Book by Arora and Barak](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~reif/courses/complectures/books/AB/ABbook.pdf).

> **$UC$:** For every $\alpha \in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace^{\ast}$, if $M_{\alpha}(\alpha) = 1$, then $UC(\alpha) = 0$; otherwise (if $M_{\alpha}(\alpha)$ outputs a different value or enters an infinite loop), $UC(\alpha) = 1$.

The undecidability of $UC$ is proved by the also well-known *"diagonalization"* technique. I can understand the technique. However, I am puzzling over a more basic problem involving the definition of $UC$.

> **My Problem:** The definition of $UC$ is based on the value of $M_{\alpha}(\alpha)$. Especially, it seem to be based on *whether a Turing Machine halts on an input*. However, the latter is undecidable (Worse still, it is undecidable due to the undecidability of $UC$!). In this sense, is the $UC$ function well-defined?

What is wrong with my opinion? How should I understand the definition of $UC$ and the relation between $UC$ and Halting Problem?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In classical logic it is possible to define a function which is not computable, and $UC$ is such a function. What probably confuses you is that you think that a function must always be given in a symbolic form, or as a set of instructions on how to compute it, or some such. But this is not necessary. Officially a function $f : A \to B$ is the same thing as a subset $F \subseteq A \times B$ satisfying the *functionality condition*:

> For every $x \in A$ there is exactly one $y \in B$ such that $(x,y) \in F$.

We may apply this to our situation to define $UC$ as the set of pairs
$$UC = \lbrace
((\alpha, x), d) \mid
(\text{$M_\alpha$ halts on $x$ and $d = 1$})
\lor
(\text{$M_\alpha$ does not halt on $x$ and $d = 0$})
\rbrace.$$
Even though nobody told us how to discover the output $d$ for a given input $(a, x)$, it is still the case that for every $(a,x)$ there is exactly one $d$. Indeed, if there were more than one then we would have a machine $M_\alpha$ which both halts and does not halt on input $x$. And if there were no such $d$, that would mean we have a machine $M_\alpha$ which neither halts nor not halts on input $x$.

In constructive logic one cannot define a non-computable function. And neither can one show that all functions are computable. So there $UC$ would not satisfy the functionality condition, and it would only define a *partial* function. But we could still talk about the fact that the Hlating problem is not decidable because the same classical argument still applies (we just avoid talking about $UC$). Assume there is a Turing machine $H$ such that:

1. $H$ halts on every input.
2. If $M_\alpha$ halts on $x$ then $H$ on input $(\alpha, x)$ outputs $1$.
3. If $M_\alpha$ does not halt on $x$ then $H$ on input $(\alpha, x)$ outputs $0$.

We now proceed with the usual diagonalization argument and construct a machine $B$ with a code $\beta$ such that $B(\beta)$ halts if, and only if, $H(\beta, \beta)$ outputs $0$. Everything here is perfectly constructive. I only took care never to assume that every machine either halts or not (such an assumption is implicit in the definition of $UC$).

So perhaps you should stick to constructive mathematics, and there will be fewer surprises for you.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of _functionality condition_ in _classical logic_. As you guess, I am a little unaccustomed to functions of this form. In the last paragraph, you mentioned that _we could still talk about the undecidability of the Halting Problem by simply skipping the things about function_. I have no idea about how to achieve this _without reduction from $UC$ function_ or something just like that. Could you explain it a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: I changed the answer to maek it more accurate. Is this better?

Comment: As a greenhand, I have to think over it. I will accept it as answer in a few of days, just waiting for some other possible perspectives on the problem. By the way, are there some well-known functions defined in the way like that of $UC$ (I mean _``not constructive''_) besides the field of Computability Theory or even Computer Science?

Comment: Sure, for example the sign function $\mathrm{sgn} : \mathbb{R} \to \lbrace -1, 0, 1 \rbrace$ which returns the sign of a real number. It is non-computable and not definable constructively. Similarly for $\mathrm{floor}$ and $\mathrm{ceil}$ (as functions on the reals, but not as functions on floating points).

Comment: A Google search guides me to the notions of _definable_ and _computable_. Are they relevant to the problem and discussion here?

Comment: "Computable" is very much relevant, because it means "can be implemented by a Turing machine". "Definable" is not as relevant to your question, but it is relevant to a part of my answer where I explain that in constructive mathematics we cannot define the function $UC$.

Answer (score 5):

The function $UC$ is well-defined. Of course, the definition is not given by some sort of algorithm but by a formal statement. In particular, the value of $UC(\alpha)$ can be either 1, if some condition $X$ is satisfied, or 0 if condition $Y$ is satisfied. But since $X$ ($M_\alpha(\alpha)=1$) is the negation of $Y$ ($M_\alpha(\alpha)\neq 1$) the definition is well-defined. It would **not** be well-defined if $X$ and $Y$ could both hold, or none of $X$ and $Y$ could hold.

Notice that a definition of a function can be expressed by an algorithm, but this is not necessarily the case. Other not-computable functions with a short definition are
$$\begin{align}
\text{BB}(\alpha)&:=\text{maximal number of cells a halting Turing machine with $\alpha$ states can print},\\ 
\text{KOL}(\alpha)&:=\text{minimal size of a Turing machine program that prints $\alpha$ and stops}.
\end{align}$$

(These are the [busy-beaver function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) and [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity).)

Comment: Thanks. I now have a better understanding (and acceptance) of the $UC$ function. In the last paragraph, two other functions not expressed by algorithms are given for further illustration. From the abbreviation (i.e., $BB(\alpha), KOL(\alpha)$, it seems that they own their importance. If so, could you give some relevant references (I can not find them). In addition, are there some well-known functions outside of Turing Machine and even Computer Science, of course not expressed by algorithms either?

Comment: @hengxin: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: @usul Thank you for references. Maybe you can add it into the post directly, for other people's convenience.